# Restrict “Look Up” feature to dictionary alone in High Sierra

Tags: macos, high-sierra, dictionary, look-up

In previous versions of macOS, there was an option to show the dictionary definition of a word by tapping it with three fingers. In High Sierra this was replaced with the Look Up feature, which pulls suggestions from sources outside of the local dictionary, opens mini windows when used on links, etc.

Is there any way to restrict this to showing dictionary definitions alone?

Comment: AFAIK no, but try disabling "Allow Spotlight Suggestions in Look up"

Comment: @JMY1000 it seems did the trick!